# writing some linguistic data in different columns

Tags: horizontal-alignment, columns

I want to write some linguistic data in three columns. I don't want to write it in a table. There must be three columns adjusting left or center.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You don't want to use a table or a tabular?  A table is a float and usually has a caption.  A tabular is just a formatting environment.  See also longtable.

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{graphicx,tabto}

\begin{document}

\NumTabs{3} % define3 equally spaced tabs starting at the left margin
\large\textbf{Italiano}:\tab Francese \tab Inglese \normalsize
\begin{itemize}
    
    \item\textbf{Libro}:\tab Livre \tab book
    \item\textbf{matita}:\tab crayon \tab pencil
\end{itemize}   
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks dear Raffaele. It was Exactly whatever I wanted.

Comment: Thanks. But now you could vote my answer and check for accepted.